# populating sql variable with select statement works but if i put that same statement in variable and try exec() it doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to populate a sql variable with a value. It works when the code is like this:

```
declare @num_records int
set @num_records = ( select  distinct count(*) as num_recs 
   from dbo.tbllookup  )
print @num_records
```

For example purpose I have made my query simpler but its a complex query and I want to put it in variable as I have to reuse the part of the query somewhere else. So I tried this but it does not work. The error says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'."

```
declare @num_records int
declare @sqlstr varchar(200)
set @sqlstr = '( select  distinct count(*) as num_recs 
   from dbo.tbllookup  )'
set @num_records = exec(@sqlstr)
print @num_records
```

I am a sql query newbie. So just want to understand the concept and want to know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use sp_executeSQL with an output parameter

See example here at the bottom  [Changing exec to sp_executesql doesn't provide any benefit if you are not using parameters correctly](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/changing-exec-to-sp_executesql-doesn-t-p)

```
declare @sqlstr Nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @num_records int
set @sqlstr = '( select  distinct @num_records =  count(*)  
                  from dbo.tbllookup  )'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sqlstr, N'@num_records INT OUTPUT', @num_records OUTPUT

print @num_records
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, you cannot populate a variable in this way. You must use `sp_executesql` to do this.

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max);
Declare @CountResult int;

Set @Sql = 'Select @Count = Count(*) From SomeTable';
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Count int OUTPUT', @CountResult OUTPUT

Select @CountResult
```

[sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)